# LoadRunner Java over HTTP protocol vs. WEB (http/html) protocol

Tags: java, loadrunner

Are there any drawabacks using JAVA over http protocol to the regular web(http/html) protocol? As in more Resource usage when running from controller as i.e. is the case with TruClient? I understand that using JAVA over http involves to import .jar files into the script location, thus at least demanding these .jar files to be on the Controller during a loadtest? 
I guess you could say that JAVA over http offers a better/more control over the AUT if the person develping/enhancing the script is a JAVA developer and not a C developer as is the case with standard http/html vuser script? Any other pros or cons of using JAVA over HTTP/HTML? I am curious because I want some (JAVA) developers enhancing a script for me and http/html scripts is not favourable as it requires C programming skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java vs HTTP for web virtual users?

1. HTTP virtual uses weigh less
2. The inclusion of Java adds a lot of complexity to the setup
3. Versions of LoadRunner support specific versions of Java.   As soon as you get a mismatched setup a lot of the dark magic gremlins appear and you have lots of issues with the execution of your tests

JAVA over HTTP

see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cr4RUlIOVOw

Comment: Thank you, and the pros are that JAVA over HTTP makes the developers able to communicate with the AUTs classes and methods from within the VUser script, right? Even though I want my developers being able to communicate with client side elements and tweak on those, with the drawbacks that includes (GUI classes or client-side activities maybe recorded via the hook. However, this is not recommended as it does not contribute to the load generation towards the server) from: http://loadrunnertnt.blogspot.no/2007/05/working-with-java-introduction.html

Comment: Java over HTTP is mostly interprocess stuff where HTTP is the carrier between front end and back end Java processes.    Operating the elements on the front end dynamically is really the focus of an automated functional testing tool such as QuickTest Professional, which is also the basis for the GUI (Graphical User Interface) Virtual User.